firebase error: module.db.collection is not a function
I am trying to use firebase to display posts, I have looked through several other stack overflows questions & answers and I think ive fixed it to use the latest SDK, but I am still getting this error when running local host(terminal displaying no errors now)
error:
error message on local host
this is my code , firebase.js & the file 'Feed.js; i am trying to use firebase with:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "###",
    authDomain: "###",
    projectId: "###",
    storageBucket: "###",
    messagingSenderId: "###",
    appId: "###"
  };

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const auth = getAuth();

export { db, auth };```

i have removed the info in firebaseConfig and replaced it with ### , it is still the default on my code
the feed.js file:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import "./Feed.css"
import CreateIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Create'
import InputOption from './InputOption'
import ImageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Image';
import SubscriptionsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Subscriptions';
import EventNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EventNote';
import CalendarViewDayIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarViewDay';
import Post from './Post';
import { db } from './firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';


function Feed() {

    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("posts").onSnapshot(snapshot => (
            setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
                {
                    id: doc.id,
                    data: doc.data(),
                }
            )))
        ));
    }, []);

    const sendPost = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        db.collection("posts").add({
            name: "Luke Knight",
            description: "this is a test",
            message: input,
            photoUrl: "",
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
    };

  return (
    <div className='feed'>
        <div className='feed__inputContainer'>
            <div className='feed__input'>
                <CreateIcon />
                <form>
                    <input value={input} 
                    onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} 
                    type="text"/>
                    <button onClick={sendPost} type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className='feed__inputOptions'>
                <InputOption Icon={ImageIcon} title="Photo" color="#70B5F9"/>
                <InputOption Icon={SubscriptionsIcon} title="Video" color="#E7A33E"/>
                <InputOption Icon={EventNoteIcon} title="Event" color="#C0CBCD"/>
                <InputOption Icon={CalendarViewDayIcon} title="Write article" color="#7FC15E"/>

            </div>
        </div>
        {posts.map(({id, data: { name, description, message, photoUrl} }) => (
            < Post 
            key={id}
            name={name}
            description={description}
            message={message}
            photoUrl={photoUrl}
            
            />
        ))}

        <Post name="Luke Knight" description="This is a test" message="This worked" />

    </div>
  )
}

export default Feed;

I am getting no errors in the console and yarn states my server is running with no problems on local host however I am getting the above error message

You're mixing the syntax of different SDK versions in your code.
Your getFirestore uses the modular syntax of the v9 and later SDKs, but then your db.collection uses the namespaced syntax from older SDKs. You can't just mix and match syntaxes, you'll have to pick one and stick with it.
The equivalent of this in namespaced syntax:
db.collection("posts").onSnapshot(snapshot => (

Is this in modular syntax:
onSnapshot(collection(db, "posts), snapshot => {

As you can see, it's mostly a matter of shuffling things around.
I copied that mostly from the documentation on listening for data with the modular web API, so I recommend keeping that handy. There's also this documentation page on upgrading from the namespaced API to the modular API, that'd good reading for this topic.
